# How to access a VM(windows based) machine using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently using machine A and I am trying to access VM B to check the VM services status.
Have already tried [How to connect to a remote Windows machine to execute commands using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961213/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-windows-machine-to-execute-commands-using-python)
Below method to no use.
Cannot use SSH so want WMI or any other solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Using wmi to start executable remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659469/python-using-wmi-to-start-executable-remotely)

Comment: Unexpected COM error it gives